# use two different adapters - android -fragment

Tags: android, adapter

I have an if and else block. if it conforms to the if condition, it will list the data in the database as imageAdapter. anasayfaAdapter will be used if elsee comes into it.

```
    if(kisiIdd.equals(userId))
    {
        adapterr = new imageAdapter(getActivity(), kullaniciList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterr);
        adapterr.setOnItemClickListener(urunlerimFragment.this);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                kullaniciList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Kullanici kullaniciModel = postSnapshot.getValue(Kullanici.class);
                    String id=kullaniciModel.getKisiId().toString();
                        kullaniciList.add(kullaniciModel);
                        kullaniciModel.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                }
                adapterr.notifyDataSetChanged();

                progressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        anasayfaAdapter = new anasayfaAdapter(getActivity(), kullaniciList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(anasayfaAdapter);
        anasayfaAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(urunlerimFragment.this);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                kullaniciList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Kullanici kullaniciModel = postSnapshot.getValue(Kullanici.class);
         String id=kullaniciModel.getKisiId().toString();

         kullaniciList.add(kullaniciModel);
         kullaniciModel.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());

                }
                anasayfaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

if the data in the database from the database if the imageAdapter to use to list. In the Else block, it will use the anasayfaAdapter adapter. Why would an algorithm fit?
but it does not happen. How do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Instead make your **RecyclerView adapter** heterogeneous rather than setting two different adapters. Use `getItemViewType()` method for that in your adapter.

Comment: but I have different methods within my adapters, so I want to use two different adapters. Because I will check the person's id from the database in the application, if the person himself is going to work on different methods if a different person will call different methods? @JeelVankhede

Comment: Yes, that's all possible by using different `ViewHolders`.

Comment: What if we want to do this in the application section and not in the adapter? @JeelVankhede